# Is it possible for me to finish a novel?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, novel

I never took formal study regarding on writing, but I'm good on imagination. I was able to take down ideas, my book will be trilogy if I could manage to put it in writing. I'm struggling on how to use the setting and how to build my character's emotion, sometimes I'm using the attitude of real person, but mostly my own emotion, decision and attitude on how to deal with the situation I'm working. So in the end the story begins on how I wanted it to be done. If I'll keep on this track, is it possible for me to finish the novel I'm working? * And I admit  I'm having trouble with my grammar.

Comment: I know the feeling, believe me! However, I think we would be able to help you more effectively if you could describe some specific difficulties you're having. I know from another question you asked that you finished your first draft – are you having difficulty editing it, or moving on to book 2 in the trilogy, for example?

Comment: Agreed that this question is far too broad in its current form, but please consider editing this into a form that's more answerable and we'll consider reopening.

Comment: Hi @manyaceist , my question was edited. :) Thanks for advising me with that.

Comment: Hi @NeilFein , my question was edited. :) Thanks for advising me with that.

Comment: Only two things will stop you from finishing your novel:  (1) You, and (2) the Grim Reaper.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be a writer, WRITE!

My personal experience is that a lot of ideas lose their allure once you start working on them for real.  So if you want to find out whether those ideas have potential, start writing right away.

If you are afraid you could spend dozens or hundreds of hours writing half a novel, only to find out that it's not worth the time you'd need to finish it, then you shouldn't start writing right away.  Do some outlining instead.  Try to develop your idea into a full plot.  Write down everything you know about your characters (no prosa, just a list), about the settings (locations, time, etc), and about the plot.  Does it work?  Does it sound like a story someone would want to read?  If not, what does it need?  Start adding more items and filling in the blanks.  Eventually, your "final" plot draft might end up being a page or 10 pages long.  There's no recommended length.  Whatever works for you is the right length.  Finally, if you like your outline, write.

Also, I read many years ago that, very often, it's very hard to finish your first novel because you ALWAYS hit a wall when you have spent so much time working on it that the initial excitement has worn off and you realise there's still a lot to do, while at the same time, you're full of fantastic new ideas for other projects.  If that happens, you have to FORCE YOURSELF to finish that novel, even if you don't like the final result.  Because if you don't finish that first novel, you will never finish any other novel.  Finish the first novel, just to prove to yourself that YOU CAN DO IT.  Then, forget about it for a couple of years.  Later, read that first novel again and realise how much you would do differently now.  You will learn a lot.

I don't recall where this advice is from, but it worked for me.  I think, but I am not sure, that it was on Diana Gabaldon's blog.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the reply.  I'll be doing it again.